Public key athentication denied
This is the error message I am getting while trying to access my VPS using SSH key, it has mever worked with the password, and the publickey is not working either, any idea what I might be missing?
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
root@50.88.2.46: Permission denied (publickey,password).
root@DESKTOP-G8UBCED1:


You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; I also note mention of root in your details; where the root account is disabled by default on Ubuntu which could be a cause, but you're without specifics as to what you're asking about.

I was able to resolve that problem, the one I am getting now is too many authentication failures. I noticed you answered my last question, thank you!

Please try SSH Permission denied (publickey) and comment about the results.

debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 1
Received disconnect from 50.88.2.46 port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from 50.88.2.46 port 22

That's the error message I am getting when I try to access my VPS via SSH using publickey authentication
